# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installs to my USB instead of my hdd

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I have an HP Spectrex360, never before used. It came with windows 10. I'm not trying to dual-boot, but rather replace the Windows OS with the Linux one. (I did initially boot into windows so I could go online and flash a USB.)

Once that was done, I followed the "Install" instructions for Ubuntu. (I will skip the parts that I experienced the first several tries, because not sure any of it is relevant.)

Eventually started completely over: flashed different, brand new USB from different machine, plugged that USB into Specter, went thru install process yet again.

Here are pics of what I wound up with (first is boot order, next two are of how what appears to be partitioned according to the Ubuntu "Disks" utility.

Additionally, when selecting "something else" during install (because the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option does not seem to actually do that...), here is what I see (third and fourth pic. Fourth pic is rest of list when I scroll down from what you see on third pic. And all of this seems excessive..?)

Could someone please tell me what the heck to do, or point me to some instructions that will?

Many thanks!
ALSO JUST NOTICED I NEED AT LEAST "10 Reputation" to post images..?! (How can I get help if I can't post images, and how can I be of help unless someone can help me learn stuff?) TRYING ANYWAY. Thanks.

Comment: If you post links to the pictures, someone will edit them in. But, if the pictures are of terminal work, it is better to copy and paste the text.

Comment: You have 11 reputation, post away.

Comment: Thank you. I no longer need to post pictures, because the problem was solved, and the solution was very strange...I'll go ahead and post it as an answer in the event this may help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The laptop I was working with has only one usb port, so I'd plugged in a multi-port device (and plugged a mouse, as well as my ISO flash drive, into that.)
When the program instructed me to "remove installation media," I was pulling out just the flash drive, possibly resulting in the loop I described in my question....

...BUT when the ENTIRE multi-port was pulled out (instead of just the flash)....the program did what it was supposed to and actually installed to the HDD.
No idea why...